# Ubuntu 14.04 problem refreshing screen

Tags: 14.04, display

I have problems of refreshing screen, but I don't know the cause of the problem. Sometimes, my screen "twinkle", that means it pass to the current view it must be display, and the previous view. For example, sometimes, when I change tab on firefox, the screen display alternatively, the older tab and the new tab. This problem disappear when i move, or refresh the page, or anything that reload the screen. It appear with firefox, but with all application.

I think there are a problem with my installation of Ubuntu, but I'm not sure, and I don't know what could cause this graphic bug.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Could you give more information on what graphics hardware you're using an what version of the driver???

Comment: My card graphic is an NVidia GTX 690, and the current drivers version install is 340.29